# Sorting a List of Class with LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a `List<MyClass>` and I want to sort it by `DateTime CreateDate` attribute of MyClass.

Is that possible with LINQ ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean by the property CreateDate which is of DateTime type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enumerate it in sorted order:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> result = list.OrderBy(element => element.CreateDate);
```

You can also use `ToList()` to convert to a new list and reassign to the original variable:

```
list = list.OrderBy(element => element.CreateDate).ToList();
```

This isn't quite the same as sorting the original list because if anyone still has a reference to the old list they won't see the new ordering. If you actually want to sort the original list then you need to use the `List<T>.Sort` method.

Comment: How can I put the latest on top ? by asc ?

Comment: `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy`

Answer (score 5):

To sort the *existing* list:

```
list.Sort((x,y) => x.CreateDate.CompareTo(y.CreateDate));
```

It is also possible to write a `Sort` extension method, allowing:

```
list.Sort(x => x.CreateDate);
```

for example:

```
public static class ListExt {
    public static void Sort<TSource, TValue>(
            this List<TSource> list,
            Func<TSource, TValue> selector) {
        if (list == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
        list.Sort((x,y) => comparer.Compare(selector(x), selector(y)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{ 
    public class Test
    {
        public void SortTest()
        {
            var myList = new List<Item> { new Item { Name = "Test", Id = 1, CreateDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) }, new Item { Name = "Other", Id = 1, CreateDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2) } };
            var result = myList.OrderBy(x => x.CreateDate);
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Have you tried using linq?"  LOL - that's what the question is about!

Answer (score 0):

Sure the other answers with `.OrderBy()` work, but wouldn't you rather make your source item inherit from `IComparable` and just call `.Sort()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
       class T  {
            public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        }
```

to use:

```
List<T> ts = new List<T>(); 
ts.Add(new T { CreatedDate = DateTime.Now }); 
ts.Add(new T { CreatedDate = DateTime.Now }); 
ts.Sort((x,y) => DateTime.Compare(x.CreatedDate, y.CreatedDate));
```

---